# Select2 4.0.1: How to return only first character matched results?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 Version 4.0.1, while searching any name, I would like to show only those records which is matched by first character. eg: I start from "c" then show only those names which start from "c". See attachment.

I tried different methods was available on stackoverflow, but no luck.
eg: tried this one also, but got this error "**select2  text.toUpperCase is not a function**"

```
$("select").select2({
    matcher: function(term, text) {
      return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0;
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: **[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jEADR/2458/)**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select2 search - match only words that start with search term](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571864/select2-search-match-only-words-that-start-with-search-term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use the full version of select2 ?
if yes, try this exemple

```
function matchStart (term, text) {
  if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (oldMatcher) {
  $("select").select2({
    matcher: oldMatcher(matchStart)
  })
});
```

Comment: no i am using normal version. I will try yours. I hope your code will solve the issue. I will update you accordingly